# Why the initialization from useEffect doesn't work for loading localStorage?

Tags: reactjs

Reference:
https://youtu.be/hQAHSlTtcmY?t=1342

I had an issue where I cannot initialize the `todos` from `useEffect` through `localStorage`. After adding two ToDo into the list and then click browser refresh button, all ToDo will not be able to load back. The trace looks as below:

```
storedTodos size:  2
App.js:41 todos size:  0
App.js:34 storedTodos size:  0
App.js:41 todos size:  0
App.js:41 todos size:  0
```

It seems to me the `setTodos(storedTodos)` doesn't work as expected. The solution is to load the initialization through `useState` shown below.

**Question**> Can someone please advice me that why this initialization doesn't work within `useEffect`?

Thank you

```
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
  // const [todos, setTodos] = useState(() => {
  //   if (localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) {
  //     const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
  //     return storedTodos;
  //   }
  //   else
  //     return [];
  // })
  const todoNameRef = useRef()

  // This doesn't work as expected
  //
  useEffect(() => {
    const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
    
    if (storedTodos) {
      console.log("storedTodos size: ", storedTodos.length)
      setTodos(storedTodos)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("todos size: ", todos.length)
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos))
  }, [todos])

  function handleAddTodo(e) {
    const name = todoNameRef.current.value
    if (name === '') return
    setTodos(prevTodos => {
      return [...prevTodos, { id: uuidv4(), name: name, complete: false }]
    })
    todoNameRef.current.value = null
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TodoList todos={todos} />
      <input ref={todoNameRef} type="text" />
      <button onClick={handleAddTodo}>Add Todo</button>
      <button>Clear Completed Todos</button>
      <div>0 left to do</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Try to replace `if(storedTodos)` with `if(storedTodos.length > 0)`. I think it might be setting todos state to empty since it may not have retrieved the local storage values in time

Comment: One more checking is required here: `if (storedTodos && storedTodos.length > 0)`

Comment: This fixed my issue. Before the change, the log looks like `storedTodos size: 2 App.js:44 todos size: 0 App.js:38 storedTodos size: 0 App.js:44 todos size: 0 App.js:44 todos size: 0`. After the fix, the log shows as `storedTodos size:  2 App.js:44 todos size:  0 App.js:44 todos size:  0 App.js:44 todos size:  2`

Comment: After adding more debug, I found the following `storedTodos size:  2
App.js:48 todos size:  0
App.js:43 storedTodos is empty
App.js:48 todos size:  0
App.js:48 todos size:  2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use `useEffect` at all in this scenario. Use your commented code to initialize the state variable. Then make a wrapper for `setTodos` to cache the value. Delete both `useEffect`s.

```
  const [todos, _setTodos] = useState(() => {
    const storedTodosString = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
    if (!storedTodosString) return [];
    return JSON.parse(storedTodosString);
  });

  function setTodos(todos) {
    if (typeof todos === 'function') {
      _setTodos((prevTodos) => {
        const newTodos = todos(prevTodos);
        if (!newTodos) return prevTodos;
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(newTodos));
        return newTodos;
      });
    } else {
      if (!todos) return;
      localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos));
      _setTodos(todos);
    }
  }
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-awp3f5?file=src%2FApp.tsx

---

Your solution doesn't work because state variables are immutable during a render. On your first render, the value of `todos` is `[]` no matter how many times you call `setTodos`. This means you are writing `[]` to localStorage on init. Strict Mode causes `useEffects` to be called twice in a single render (during development) so order of operations goes:

1. Read localStorage, call `setTodos` with stored value
2. Write `[]` to localStorage
3. Read `[]` from localStorage, call `setTodos` with `[]`
4. Write `[]` to localStorage.

Comment: I tried this solution and here is the log `storedTodos size:  2
App.js:38 storedTodos size:  2
App.js:58 todos size:  0
App.js:58 todos size:  2`. It looks like the updated useEffect is still called twice with empty size. The first time is ignored and second time is set. So I believe the `useEffect(... [])` is called with an empty loaded `storedTodos` and this is the reason that caused the problem if we don't check `length`.

Comment: That's a result of strict mode, which generally doesn't play well with refs. ie. useEffect is called twice consecutively every render. If you want to continue with strict mode, you'll want to adopt an immutable approach instead of using refs. Otherwise just disable it.

Comment: I added another solution that will work with strict mode, and is probably a better option.

Comment: With your update and my original code, I see the following log `storedTodos size:  2
App.js:38 storedTodos size:  2
App.js:58 todos size:  0
App.js:58 todos size:  2`.   As you can see, we still see `todos size:  0` even if you ignored the first one. In this case, why it didn't wipe out the localStorage and todos? Instead, it shows `todos size:  2` in the next cycle.

Comment: It shouldn't log `todos size: 0` because you were supposed to remove that `useEffect` call. It does that because of strict mode.

Comment: I updated to include a complete solution that works with strict mode and is probably better than my other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your `useEffect` hook with `todos` as dependency runs every time the todos state changes, which includes the initial render when todos is `null`. This causes the localStorage to be overwritten with an empty array, which then prevents the other `useEffect` hook from loading the stored todos.

To fix this, you can move the localStorage logic inside the setTodos function and remove `useEffect` with `todos` as dependency.

For example:

```
setTodos((prevTodos) => {
  const todos = [...prevTodos, { id: uuidv4(), name: name, complete: false }];
  localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos));
  return todos;
});
```

Comment: One issue with this solution is that the state of checked status is not tracked through onClick event of the `Add Todo` button, so the checked status is not correctly saved.

Comment: That's a good point, but I think you can set localStorage item in that case using setState callback. In my opinion, reducing useEffect is good for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a check to ensure the state is only set if the value from localStorage has resolved. Replace `if(storedTodos)` with `if(storedTodos.length > 0)`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
    // added check
    if (storedTodos && storedTodos.length > 0) {
      console.log("storedTodos size: ", storedTodos.length)
      setTodos(storedTodos)
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: My understanding is that you do NOT want to check the `storedTodos.lengt`h in the second `useEffect` because it is required when the object is cleared.

Comment: yeah that's a good point, you might want to get rid of that use effect all together and update localstorage in the function that updates the item